# Remove Default column from public_activity rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, public-activity

I am using public_activity gem to track some changes in a model. I have no need for default **receipt_id** and **receipent_type** columns.

SO i just remove them from migration. But i am getting error while creating public_activity like this in controller

```
@batch.create_activity key: create, owner: current_user
```

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in MyController#update
>   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'parameters' in 'field list': INSERT
>   INTO `activities

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand this gem creates a separate DB entry for each change (in the same way as the paper_trail gem). This means that you need the `id` and `type` columns so the gem can match it to the object they originate from. Should work fine if you don't remove those columns.

Comment: Yes, its working fine but i don't want to add those columns. So you mean to say that no column can be removed from this gem migration

Comment: Yes exactly, you can't remove those columns without loosing the functionality of the gem.